# Transact-SQL Job permission

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, jobs

I have 2 SQL servers: A & B. On A, I have a stored proc that processes some data from B and then dumps the results into a table on A. I need to schedule a job to run this proc.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189064(SQL.105).aspx, it's the Job Owner that gets used when running the job. (Can't set a "Run as" on the job step for TSQL step/job.)

How the network people have set these machines / security up for is to use a third server, C, with centralised logins stored on that. So my login is: SERVERC\SEAN. This login has access to both DB servers, A & B. The proc runs fine if I execute when logged in and connected to Server A.

So I set the job owner as SERVERC\SEAN, but when the job runs, the error message is:
"Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. Login failed for user SERVERC\SERVERA$"

Why is it running as Network Service, and some weird login combination, instead of as the job owner, as instructed? How do I get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: How are you executing the job?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "how"? It's a scheduled job. If I let the scheduler run it, or if I execute it via Management Studio, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [post](http://www.techbubbles.com/sql-server/running-sql-server-jobs-with-different-user-accounts-in-sql-2008/), it should do what you want it to.

**Editing to show most helpful link**
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/54dff132-b9c9-4753-b0c5-2134bf7f4327

Comment: No, that didn't help. When I click the ellipsis, I only get a list of users on SERVER A, not on SERVER C. If I try typing in SERVERC\SEAN, then it won't accept that user. If I try SERVERA\SEAN (I also have local logins) then the job fails - because SERVERA\SEAN doesn't have access to SERVERB database ("Access to the remote server is denied because the current security context is not trusted").

Comment: Okay, so you don't have a network service login that can be used?

Comment: A "network service login"? No... I don't think so. How would that be any different from the login on SERVERC\SEAN?

Comment: @SeanW The issue is that "SERVERC\SEAN" is a local login for that server - which explains why you can't access SERVERA with that login.  So, if you want to be able to access multiple servers by way of impersonation you're going to need a domain login that has access to all three.  Your other option is the link the servers, if they can see each other, and that should allow you to do what you want as well.  Does this make sense?

Comment: It's doesn't really make sense, because I am not familiar with security/network (I'm just a dev!). But as far as I know, SERVERC was set up specifically as a centralised (domain?) login server. So my login on SERVERC has access to SERVERA & SERVERB. Therefore if I could set the job to use that user, it should all be fine. But I can't, as described above. I'm not sure about what linking the servers entails, I'll try ask them - but what is it exactly I need to ask? Thanks!!

Comment: @SeanW The name of the domain on the network is SERVERC? If so let's backup then. Did you create the SQL Server Agent proxy?

Comment: I didn't do the install/setup. The network/security guys just give us the environment. So I'm not 100% sure what's been setup and how. But their idea was that all (centralised) logins are on SERVERC. So I need the TSQL job on SERVERA to run with a SERVERC login. That doesn't look possible. I think I'm going to convert it to an SSIS job, that calls the proc. SSIS jobs can use proxies. I guess I was just trying to find out why TSQL jobs couldn't use remote logins.

Comment: @SeanW You know, you might check this out. It appears that if you run the T-SQL procedure using SQLCMD it will allow a proxy - ha! http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/54dff132-b9c9-4753-b0c5-2134bf7f4327

Comment: I think that's as good as it's going to get. Thanks, @mperrenoud03